# Why do actuaries roll high values of some variables like seats (categorical variable) into a lower value?

Tags: categorical-data

I was looking at an example from [Predictive Modeling Applications in Actuarial Science](http://instruction.bus.wisc.edu/jfrees/jfreesbooks/PredictiveModelingVol1/index.htm)

And, in one of the examples (below) -- he moves cars with 6, 7, 8 and 9 seats into the categorical variable 6+ -- **why does he do that?**

```
#
# Roll high values of seats (categorical variable) into a lower value
idx <- dta$seats %in% c("6", "7", "8", "9")
dta$seats[idx] <- "6+"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a part of the feature engineering stage in modeling.
Two key concepts in features engineering are:
1) Features should represent reality(or our assumption about reality).
2) Features different values should have good distribution(where good might mean different things).

Bucketing over 6 seats cars into one value lets one keep its reality representation while improving its feature values distribution.